# I am getting null data grid, when i bind with datatable in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

When I bind  datagrid in wpf with of linq lambda expression its fill datagrid but when I try to convert this linq result in datatable then its fill null datagrid below my code which I tried ....

```
var join = dm.Export_Matrilas_s
             .Where(rh => rh.Material_type == 5)
             .Join(dm.Parti_Infos, p => p.Parti_Id, w => w.Parti_Id, (p, w) => new { p.Export_Matrilas_id, p.Material_type, p.Owncom, w.Organization, p.Date })
             .Join(dm.Own_Company_Infos, r => r.Owncom, y => y.Company_Id, (r, y) => new { r, y.Organization_Name })
             .Join(dm.Material_Types, n => n.r.Material_type, b => b.Id, (n, t) => new { n.r.Export_Matrilas_id, t.Meterial_Name, n.Organization_Name, n.r.Organization, n.r.Date })
             .ToList();

DataTable gettbl = ToDataTable(join);
mygride.DataContext = gettbl.DefaultView;
```

Here I convert into datatable using method

```
  public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)// T is any generic type
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            // table.Columns.Add(prop.DisplayName,prop.PropertyType);
            table.Columns.Add(prop.DisplayName, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[props.Count];
         DataRow row;

        foreach (var record in data)
        {
            row = table.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                values[i] = props[i].GetValue(record) != null ? props[i].GetValue(record) : DBNull.Value;
            }

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        table.Rows.Add(values);

        return table;
    }
```

Here is my xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Iqbal_Silks.Export_Tanee_Records"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Height="700" Width="900">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../Themes/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid >
     <DataGrid x:Name="mygride" Margin="3,243,10,64" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" CanUserResizeRows="False"   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="VerticalFirst" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Export ID" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Export_Matrilas_id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Materials " Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Meterial_Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Organization_Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Organization}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Excel Records" x:Name="btnviewchallan_Copy"  Style="{StaticResource Hdrclose}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="616,641,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Height="27" Click="BtnviewchallanCopyClick" />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,644,768,32">
            <Button Name="btnFirstPage" Content="&lt;&lt;" Click="btnFirstPage_Click"/>
            <Button Name="btnPreviousPage" Content="&lt;" Click="btnPreviousPage_Click"/>
            <Label Name="lblPageIndex" Content="{Binding ElementName=root,
                Path=PageIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto"/>
            <Label Content="of"/>
            <Label Name="lblPageNumber" Content="{Binding ElementName=root,
                Path=NumberOfPages, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto"/>
            <Button Name="btnNextPage" Content="&gt;" Click="btnNextPage_Click"/>
            <Button Name="btnLastPage" Content="&gt;&gt;" Click="btnLastPage_Click"/>
        </StackPanel> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: ya .. i  tried  with break point,  ToDataTable() work perfectly and its also add row and column value but its not serve filled table

Comment: when i bind with the help of result of linq then its give record , but when i convert into table then its not fill record as same to mapped in your XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to bind a `DataGrid`:

It can be done either via the `DataContext` property like you are trying to do:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = gettbl.DefaultView;
```

which is not correct here because your `DataContext` is in this case the `DataTable` itself (gettbl) so this would be correct:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = gettbl;
```

if you however use the `DataContext` you also need to set the `ItemsSource` in `XAML` to:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DefaultView}">
```

or the other way is to directly use the `ItemsSource` property (then you do not need any extra code in `XAML`)

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = gettbl.DefaultView;
```

Besides I think your `ToDataTable` method has a bug.

You add only empty rows to the `DataTable` and it has one row more than the source collection.

```
DataRow row;
foreach (var record in data)
{
    row = table.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        values[i] = props[i].GetValue(record) != null ? props[i].GetValue(record) : DBNull.Value;
    }
    // You do not set the row columns anywhere.
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    // This would work but I'm not sure what you are trying to do.
    // table.Rows.Add(values);
}

// You add an extra row here: is this intended?
table.Rows.Add(values);
```

I'm also not sure if it is such a good idea to build the data table columns based on the specified object properties because you've already defined columns for your data grid and if the `T` has different properties than the already defined columns then they won't match and you won't see anything.

Perhaps you are already doing this but if not consider using an interface that specifies column names or make your data grid autogenerate columns.